# php include header and footer in complex file structure

Tags: php, header, include, structure, traversal

I have to following file structure:

```
ROOT
index.html
    INCLUDES
        header.html
        footer.html
    FOLDER1
        FOLDER2
            FOLDER3
                FOLDER4
                    file.php
```

When I use

```
include('includes/header.html');
```

in my `index.html` file, the header is pulled in correctly.

However, I cannot get it to traverse the file structure from `file.php`. I have tried the following:

```
include('../../../../includes/header.html');
```

Can you spot what I am doing wrong? Is there a way to do it so I can just specify

`include('includes/header.html');`

regardless of which page I am on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/header.html');
```

Comment: not much point in using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR if you're just going to hardcode a dir separator inside the rest of the string. But +1 for the right answer otherwise.

Comment: Using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is no longer recomened. Every OS PHP operates on supportes '/'.

Answer (score 0):

The default method to do this is to adjust the [include_path](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-include-path.php) variable from php, so any file can include your library folder, regardless of the filesystem position.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var=(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');
    require_once($var.'header.html');
echo $var;//you find how many directory back you are
```